# Converting a reserved orderID to live order

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

Our Magento 1.5 site is currently under extremely heavy load for the holidays.  We're occasionally (5-10 a day) getting customer service calls about orders that were paid for but that were never finalized in Magento.  Many of them are Paypal, which might be expected, but some are credit cards.

I can locate the quote and reserved OrderID in the DB.

Anyone know what would be involved in converting the reserved order to a live order?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [cart.order](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/api/cart#cart.order) method of the API to create an order from a quote.